# Google Maps for Android when installed from Google Play

Tags: android, admob, google-maps-android-api-2

I recently finished my application and everything works fine, but when upload to Google Play there are two things we did not work for me:
The Android Google Map V2, that only shows a white screen.
The AdMob advertising banner, that doesn't appear.

Anyone knows that may be happening?

Comment: Did you change the Map API key to use the one generated with the SHA1 of the signed application ?

Comment: No. Do you know any tutorial to make this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: Carefully read each step and follow them. All you need is there. (At least for the maps)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `proguard` (looks like) add following to your proguard-project.txt

```
-keep class com.google.ads.**

-dontwarn com.google.ads.** 

-keep class com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }

-keep interface com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }
```

this is important